# Java regex for detecting version with optional period

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to find a proper regex in java to detect all version 1 from large content. And I only care with just version 1, version 1.0, or version 1.0 but not 1.1. The test string can then be followed any other character or end of line.

How do I do that in java?

Thanks in advance

```
    String regex="(version)(\\s)(1|1\\.0)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m   = null;

    String testString1="version 1";
    m = p.matcher(testString1);
    System.out.println (m.find());

    String testString2="version 1.0";
    m = p.matcher(testString2);
    System.out.println (m.find());

    String testString3="version 1.1";  // should not match
    m = p.matcher(testString3);
    System.out.println (m.find());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `version` string in a longer string then use this lookahead regex:

```
\bversion\s+1(?:\.0)?(?=\s|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CLTP2j/1)

In Java:

```
final String regex = "\\bversion\\s+1(?:\\.0)?(?=\\s|$)";
```

`(?=\\s|$)` is positive lookahead to assert that we have a whitespace or line end after version number.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava

Comment: Just trying to understand better here, what is the different between ?: and the lookahead ?=

Comment: Lookahead does only assertion no matching so when you do `.group()` you will only get the text you want to match.

Answer (score 0):

Proposal:

```
"(version)\\s(1(\\.0)?)([^\\.0-9].*|$)"
```

1. The string "version" needs to be present
2. followed by any whitespace
3. then a single "1"
4. optionally followed by ".0"
5. and the next char either (cannot be "." or any digit (think 1.01 is forbidden, as well as 1.0.1)) or (is the end of the string)

Comment: Hi @pintxo I don't think that works on "blah version 1" if the last character is one(1) itself, then it won't work.

Comment: True, I added the possibility for being at the end of the string.